# AES Mix columns bit example

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis

I have been given a 4x4 matrix and each entry is an 8-bit long byte. I have been given the 4x4 matrix that I need to multiply each column by of the first matrix by.

$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 & 1 & 1\\\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 1 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

The method that I have been told to use seems confusing. I have searched around the internet and found many examples with polynomials but I'm not supposed to use this method.

All I have been told is:

Multiplying by 01 does nothing
 Multiplying by 02 corresponds to multiplying the byte by 10 (because 2 is 10 in binary). This
is simply a left shift by one place. If the left-hand bit of the original byte was 1, then XOR the
answer with 100011011.
 Multiplying by 03 corresponds to multiplying the byte by 11 (because 3 is 11 in binary). This is
a left shift, followed by an XOR with the original byte. Again, if the left-hand bit of the original
byte was 1, then XOR the answer with 100011011.

I find the XOR bit strange as well - because that is a string of 9 bits and the bytes are only 8.

Can anyone make sense of this or point me in the direction of a good example?

Comment: this [AES encryption algorithm (MIX COLUMNS)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57687/aes-encryption-algorithm-mix-columns?rq=1) and [AES Mix Column Transformation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51447/aes-mix-column-transformation?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns) we will see this part of the code;

- `h = (unsigned char)((signed char)r[c] >> 7);`
- `b[c] = r[c] << 1;`
- `[c] ^= 0x1B & h;`

`h` stores the leftmost bit of `c`

`c` is x-or'ed with `0x1b` but **not with** `0x11b`  why?

When shifting `r` left by one, the MSB value is discarded. Before discarding, we hold this value with `h`.

- If `h==0` than modulus operation is not required. The `0x1B & h = 0x0` so there is no x-or with `0x1b`
- If `h=1` than modulus operation is required. The `0x1B & h = 0x1B`. The x-or with `0x1b` is performed.
- **Note that:** it is not x-or with `0x11b` it is with `0x1b` since we discarded the MSB `1` while shifting. Therefore, there is no need to x-or with `0x11b`, x-oring with `0x1b` is enough. Now, it is clear that everthing is in Bytes.

### A small example;

Here [ ] represents 8-bit.

Let multiply $a = (x^7+x^6+x^3+x)$ by $\{2\}$

- binary representation of  $a = [11001010]$
- $h = 1 = [00000001]$
- $b = a \ll 1 = 1[10010100]$ but everthing is in Bytes, therefore
- $b = [10010100]$
- $h \wedge 0x1b = [00000001] \wedge [00011011] = [00011011] = 0x1b$
- $b \oplus 0x1b = [10010100] \oplus [00011011] = [10001111] = 0x8f$

Comment: Hi this is quite difficult to follow, is there a concrete example some where?

Comment: Which part is difficult?